# How to have ie9's debugger display the line of an error in the console

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug  some compatibility issues I've been having with ie9. The only problem is I'm not getting the line number the error is occurring on the console. It just tells me "error invalid argument" and nothing else no line numbr. Is there an option in the debugger tools (f12) that i can set so I can see what line number of my code is causing this error in the console similar to how chrome developer tools does it? My version of ie is 9.0.8112.1624 update version 9.0.23.

Comment: There is an option for `Start Debugging` in Script tab i guess, tried that?

Comment: Have your console open when you start, hit ctrl-F5 to ensure you are looking at a cacheless refresh. I believe you should be able to double click on the error to get the line number but I recall this doesn't always work, and that IE9 console sometimes being deceptive (i.e. not halting on all errors).

As previous poster suggested, go to the DEBUG and start debugging. You should also place breakpoints in areas you think this might be occurring in. Using the debugger and breakpoints was the best way NOT to miss these errors.

Comment: Starting the debugging doesn't do anything. All of the code executes regradless. Man this is frustrating.